# how can one obtain all combinations of a vector?

Tags: matlab, math, permutation

I want to find all possible variations (combinations) of a vector, choosing various numbers of elements from that vector.

For example, suppose I have the vector:

`x = [1 2 3 4 5];`

I can determine the number of combinations for each number of chosen elements:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5]';

n = numel(x);
for k = 1:n
   combs(k) = nchoosek(n,k);
end

sum(combs)
```

This results in:

`combs = 5    10    10     5     1`

`sum(combs) = 31`

I want a way to store all 31 of these combinations in an array, for example a cell array, with `n` cells, within each is an array in which each row is a vector combination of the elements.

e.g. at `k = 4`:

```
combs{4} = 

1 2 3 4
1 2 3 5
1 2 4 5
1 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
```

Is there an existing function that does this, or what would be the most simple approach to this?

Comment: You can simply change your loop to calculate `combs{k} = nchoosek(x,k);`.

Comment: oh geez. I totally missed the vector input part. Thanks! This is it for sure.

Comment: Does order matter?

Answer (score 2):

Call [`nchoosek`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) with a vector as first input, using [`arrayfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) (or equivalently `for`) to loop over the number of picked elements:

```
n = 5;
combs = arrayfun(@(k) nchoosek(1:n,k), 1:n, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: thanks, you and Beaker got it for sure. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using [dec2bin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) , [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
[a b] = find(dec2bin(1:2^numel(x)-1)=='1');
combs = accumarray(a,x(b),[],@(c){c});
```